# Get dhcp ip from a specific server

Tags: networking, dhcp, linux-networking

In a network that comes with two dhcp servers, how can I get network configured from one server instead of the other?

Let's say there are 2 dhcp servers named A and B. My computer always get network configured from server A, and it's not what I wanted. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, which DHCP Client do you use? There are some different around.

Considerung you are using the standard one from the ISC, you need to put a like like this in your dhclient.conf:

```
reject 10.0.0.5;
```

Where you replace the IP of course with the IP of the server whose offers you don't want. That's it.

For futher information take a look at the man page of dhclient.conf or here: http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient.conf